# Newbie is getting errors when trying populate listview from datatable

Tags: c#, listview, datatable

I have followed the examples in previous questions and am still getting errors when trying to populate a listview control from a datatable.
Here is my code

```
EvintoDataSet dsAppQualification = new EvintoDataSet();
EvintoDataSetTableAdapters.AppQualificationTableAdapter taAppQualification = 
     newEvintoDataSetTableAdapters.AppQualificationTableAdapter();

EvintoDataSet.AppQualificationDataTable dtAppQualification;
EvintoDataSet.AppQualificationRow drAppQualification;               
dtAppQualification = taAppQualification.GetAppQualification();
dsAppQualification.Tables.Add(dtAppQualification);


lvAppQualification.Items.Clear();


for (int i = 0; i < dtAppQualification.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drow = dtAppQualification.Rows[i];

    // Only row that have not been deleted
    if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        // Define the list items
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["Queston"].ToString());
        // Add the list items to the ListView
        lvAppQualification.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

I am getting an invalid argument error
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Andy

Comment: In which line the `InvalidArgument` is thrown.

Comment: What are you using? WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given much information on the error that you are getting, such as the line in which the error occurs, I can only make an assumption of what is causing the error. I think you need to add columns to your listview before adding any items, probably right before the 'for' loop .